# Unable to mount NTFS HDD

Tags: mount, hard-disk, ntfs

I am trying to mount an external USB HDD, but it does not work. When I try to mount the drive with

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb_hdd
```

the response is the following error message: `Failed to calculate free MFT records: No such file or directory`

Same result with different mount options `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb_hdd`, `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb_hdd`.

I tried to fix the issue with `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1` which outputs

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda1 was processed successfully.
```

When mounting the same error message as above is thrown. I am looking for any advice on how to fix this issue!

Best, malluss

Comment: Either your hdd is dying/dead (`badblocks`) or you still have NTFS errors (run `chkdsk /F` under Windows). `ntfsfix` is a barebone utility which often doesn't really fix anything.

Comment: Maybe the disk its corrupted. Maybe you shrinked and growing it?. In other forums mention that this tool was helpfull: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: A word of caution: if the HDD is indeed dying running `badblock` may actually make restoring data less possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I was able to solve it. Booting into Windows with the HDD attached the HDD triggered the drive check automatically and corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me by the past, it is likely the hard drive wasn't properly unmounted by Windows.
What did the trick for me :

- boot back into Windows,
- browse the hard drive
- cleanly unmounit it (if USB), or properly shut Windows down (you may want to make sure "Fast Boot" isn't enabled in Windows' power settings)
- boot back under linux and try again.

If it's a USB disk, instead of the above you can simply attach it to any another Windows machine and "safely disconnect" the drive, this should do the trick as well.